# How to install mariaDB connector tar

Tags: 16.04, mariadb

Have just downloaded mariadb-connector-c-2.3.3-linux-x86_64.tar. Wish to know the best way to install it to a ubuntu 16.04 server.

Comment: You'd need to tar -xvf the tarfile and then run configure and install.  However you would have to manage upgrading it in perpetuity.  A better way might be to sudo add-apt repository mariadb_repo; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install mariadb-connector.

Comment: @jones0610 thanks for the info. If I already have mariaDB installed, do I still need to sudo add-apt repository mariadb_repo; sudo apt-get update; ?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 20.04...

```
sudo apt-get install libmariadb3 libmariadb-dev
```